# Error when trying to run multiple mysqli queries

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am currently trying to make a website, and within this website it *requires* queries that are stacked, or inside each other.

Here's what I'm working with:

```
<?php
    if($getSections = $con->query("SELECT * FROM sections")) {
        if($getSections->num_rows > 0) {
            while($section = $getSections->fetch_assoc()) {
                $sectionID = $section['sectionID'];
                echo '<br>' .$section['sectionID']. ' ' .$section['sectionName'];
                if($getItems = $con->query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE sectionID=$sectionID")) {
                    if($getItems->num_rows > 0) {
                        while($item = $getItems->fetch_assoc()) {
                            echo '<br>' .$item['itemID']. ' ' .$item['itemName'] ' ' .$item['sectionID'];
                        };
                    } else {
                        echo '<p class="alert">No Items</p>';
                    };
                };
                $getItems->close();
            };
        } else {
            echo '<p class="alert">No Sections</p>';
        };
    };
    $getSections->close();
?>
```

When I run this I get an error:

> 500 - Internal server error.
>
> There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

, but when I run:

```
<?php
    if($getSections = $con->query("SELECT * FROM sections")) {
        if($getSections->num_rows > 0) {
            while($section = $getSections->fetch_assoc()) {
                $sectionID = $section['sectionID'];
                echo '<br>' .$section['sectionID']. ' ' .$section['sectionName'];

            };
        } else {
            echo '<p class="alert">No Sections</p>';
        };
    };
    $getSections->close();
?>
```

I don't get an error, am I doing something wrong? or is there something wrong with my web server?

Comment: Yes `$sectionID`is no where defined  what you are ussing in your second query. thanks.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh even after defining it, it still get the same error.

Comment: Also  do what @Ed Cottrell says and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error in the form of a missing period (`.`) in this line:

```
echo '<br>' .$item['itemID']. ' ' .$item['itemName'] . ' ' .$item['sectionID'];
```

Comment: Thanks, blasted periods, hard to spot.